# trouble running adb with Samsung Vibrant

Tags: android

First, I should mention that I am a beginner at Android development.

I just bought a Samsung Vibrant and I'm trying to connect to it with adb.  When I connect the phone and do a "adb devices" it didn't display anything.  So, I checked device Manager and the phone was listed under disk drives.  I tried downloading the adb driver for the phone and installing it manually.  SAMSUNG Android Composite ADB Interface was listed under the ADB Interface after that.  But, the device status is Device Cannot Start.

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same problem and its Windows being a piece of crap.  Plugged into my Mac and it just works no driver install needed.  I have reinstalled the drivers a crap ton of times on windows still can't get it to work >.<

Answer (score 3):

Did you select `enable usb debugging` in the settings?